# Credentials for access to AWS API's from static S3 websites

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

If I were to host a static website on S3, and it included the AWS javascript API which called other AWS services, where would I store/retrieve the correct AWS credentials for authorisation?

I understand that an EC2 environment can have these credentials in the environment, but is this possible in a static S3, while not exposing credentials in any way?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your use case.

If you try for example to authenticate a user you could use [Amazon Cognito](https://aws.amazon.com/cognito/).

A Code example can be found here: [Using the JavaScript SDK](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/using-amazon-cognito-user-identity-pools-javascript-examples.html)